# "Cannot open ..(document)" error for just the users with full control

Tags: 2013, document-library, permissions

I have a document library but when a user with full control for these document cannot open the document. But users with just read,view permission can open them.

And the users with full control for the document library can add a new item or do other things except opening.

The documents which cannot be opened by the full control users, are always updated every day for once. Just the datas inside of them are updated and these full control users have to open them.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can anyone help me please? It happens every week. And the error disappear by itself after one or two day but the documents are important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.The document that cannot be opened is a 97 **ppt**. When I save it as **pptx** into the document folder, it can be edited and saved easily by just open it from the website.